# Can a PHP for loop with number array start with NULL and also have 0?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, numbers

I am working with some legacy PHP code so re-writing this isn't an option at this point but I have a dropdown for number of years and months of employment and currently they go from 0 - 11, 0 - 65. Can a PHP loop array numbers starting at NULL, which adds -Select- as the default forcing user to make a selection, but also have 0 as the starting number?

I've tried:

```
for ($i = NULL; $i <= 11; $i++) {
echo $i;
}
```

But 0 is no loner an option

This is what I have currently:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 11; $i++) {
echo $i;
}
```

I need it to display as: 
-Select-
0
1
2
3
4
etc

Comment: Is this the real loop? How does that end up in a `<select>`? You have no delimiters between the numbers, so this will print `01234567891011`

Comment: What is the actual output that the AJAX client is expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echo the text before echoing the numbers using a loop.

```
<?php
echo '-Select-';
for($i = 0; $i <= 11; ++$i) {
    echo $i;
}
```

Comment: This worked but I'm getting an AJAX HTTP error occurred. Is there a way to ignore this in the output?

Comment: @svsdnb Why did you ask how tp print it if it will then cause an AJAX error?

Comment: because I didn't know using echo would cause an AJAX error until just now.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL++` would not increase the value of NULL, which is essentially nothing. Why not start at -1, and `if ($i == -1)` then echo select?

It would look like this:

```
for ($i = -1; $i <= 11; $i++) {
   if ($i == -1) {
       echo '-Select-';
   } else {
       echo $i;
   }
}
```